# React CORS being blocked when uploading to s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have a create form that is working, however, my images don't seem to be uploading to S3 due to CORS

I get the following

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://henrywatches-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

I have the following `fetch` request

```js
if (isValid) {
  fetch("/api/collections/create", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(() => uploadFile(this.state.images, this.s3Config))
    .then(
      () => this.setState({ successMsg: true }),
      () => this.setState(initalState)
    )
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Like I mentioned the form is working and a record does get created, it's just S3 `.then(() => uploadFile(this.state.images, this.s3Config))` that is being blocked. I have setup cors using express but as S3 is happening in the front-end cors pops up again as it's not happening server-side.

I've tried `mode: 'cors'` but that doesn't do anything in terms of fixing the error.

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK success response?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set these headers on your back-end:

1. `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` with value `'*'`
2. `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'` with value `'*'`
3. `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'` with value 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,
   OPTIONS'

This will get rid of the error.

**But how to actually set the headers?**

There is at least one middleware on npm for handling CORS in Express: [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors).

This is how to set custom response headers, from the [ExpressJS DOC](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.set)

```
res.set(field, [value])
```

Set header field to value

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

or pass an object to set multiple fields at once.

```
res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  'ETag': '12345'
})
```

Aliased as

```
res.header(field, [value])
```

Comment: Where do I set them? In terms of express I have `app.use(cors());` in my `app.js`

Comment: Looking at the docs, `app.use(cors());` should be enough as that's across all origins and requests.

Comment: Unless I can add it to the route server side and pass it into react?

Comment: Update us, did it work by just doing app.use(cors()); ?
In general, the headers i've typed above are good for any back end (I usually develop on laravel, so I gave you the raw headers that worked in my past experience)

Comment: So I moved to the `uploadFile` before the catch and also added a cors configuration to my s3 bucket I'm now getting this response https://i.gyazo.com/f5f9bb811f7aa96eaed4e946398b6d2e.png

Comment: It seems like there's an error with the request you're sending. Try sending a trivial http request to a very simple route that just returns hello world and see if the error still comes up. If it doesn't then you need to debug your frontend request.

Comment: My API is working, records are actually being created when I submit the form, it's just uploading to S3 that's the issue